# Does Saxon provide a way to maintain the insertion order of keys in a map?

Tags: saxon

When serializing a map to JSON, Saxon seemingly does not maintain insertion order of the keys. While I know that JSON does not require this, it would help for diagnostics and reducing end user confusion.

Is there some way I can achieve this, perhaps by implementing a custom serializer? Or does the order get lost earlier in the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon (the Java/.NET version) has two implementations of XDM maps, the HashTrieMap and the DictionaryMap, and neither maintains order. Both use hash structures that randomize the position on insertion, so there is no way of recovering it. Equally, Saxon-JS uses a HashTrie structure that doesn't preserve order.

We've hit this problem ourselves generating SEF files for Saxon-JS. This is a JSON-based format, and it's very hard to read if the properties are in random order. So we implemented the serialization option `saxon:property-order` which allows you to define an ordering for properties in the output. It doesn't enable you to maintain the original input order, but it does enable you to order the output in a way that makes sense for human readers.

Like all Saxon extensions to the W3C specs, this requires Saxon-PE or higher.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Slightly related follow-up question: what is the easiest way to include this option dynamically based on what Saxon version you are running? I can do it by having two `xsl:output` elements and then adding a `use-when` attribute that checks the result of `system-property('xsl:product-version') `, but perhaps there is an easier way?

Comment: I can think of other ways, e.g. using `xsl:output/@parameter-document`, but I don't think they're significantly easier.